# Why does the content disappear when I try to customize the scroll-bar?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to customize the scroll-bar. I set the current scroll-bar's `width` to `0` in order to start with my own scroll-bar, but by the time I set the height to `100%` of my `div`, I wanted it to act like scroll-bar ,the text which were in the `.content` disappeared and I'm stuck with this issue.

The following is my code I tried so far.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #CD5C5C;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}

.scrollbar {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #2F4F4F;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="scrollbar">
      <div class="scrollball"></div>
    </div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: no reason to run this in the snippet because it gives different result

Comment: we should be able to run the code to see the result otherwise we cannot help and your actual code show no issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scollbar is pushing the content out of the way, as they are display: block;

Two display: block; elements will not share the same row unless given a `float` styling.

Use an absolute positioned element or make your html structure different to fix this. I recommend using two top level elements, one wrapping your content and one wrapping your scrollbar. Either use `float` or another `display` styling to such as flex to fix.